# react router stacking url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hello I am using react router and have a slight problem. For some reason the url is stacking. IE: /blog/show/blog/edit/blog/show
It happens only on show or edit on my blog. If I click any other links the url fixes itself IE: /resume
My react router code is:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={About} />
        <Route path="projects" component={Projects}>
            <Route path="calculator" component={Calculator} />
            <Route path="stopwatch" component={Timer} />
            <Route path="todo" component={Todo} />
            <Route path="clock" component={Clock} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="resume" component={Resume} />
        <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="blog" component={Blog}>
            <Route path="show/:id" component={ShowPost} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/api/edit/:id" component={EditPost} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

The code that links my /blog to /blog/edit and /blog/show

```
 <Link to={`blog/show/${post.id}`} className="card-footer-item">View</Link>

    { auth ? <Link to={`api/edit/${post.id}`} className="card-footer item">
                Edit
             </Link>
    : null }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router does not support relative locations when navigatinb. You will need to make the `to` prop passed to the `<Link>` absolute.

If you need to create the pathname based off of the current location, the component rendered by a `<Route>` has the current location injected as a prop, so you can access that as `this.props.location.pathname`.

Comment: Do you mind showing me a code example of what you mean that way I can fully understand it? Thank you :)

Comment: Was it just a matter of prepended a `/` to the `to` pathnames. I was looking at this again and wasn't completely sure if it was a relative path issue or not. Either way, glad you were able to get it fixed.

Comment: Yea once i made it absolute in my <Router> and in my <Link> it worked. Thanks mate