# React Router navigation URL is appended to existing URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an error with the react-router-dom

I have one component that I'm rendering with the following:

```
<Route path='/categories/:url_type' component={Categories} exact />
```

Based on the url a different argument, either "following" or "all" , is passed into the react router and something different is rendered inside the component.

But there is an error:
Whenever I want to render my component with the second argument "following" like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/following
```

, the url of the site I previously accessed isn't cleared.
So if I have been on a "profile" site, I would instead get this

```
http://localhost:3000/profile/categories/following
```

As a result, I get an error and nothing is rendered.

This is the link from where I access it in my html(Material UI):

```
const sections= [
    { title: 'All Categories', url: 'categories/all' },
    { title: 'Following', url: "categories/following"},
  ]
// I'm merging to arrays in my code, this is for simplicity

{sections.map((section)=>(
  <Link component={RouterLink} to={section.url}>{section.link}</Link>
))}
```

This how I process the links. The function "allCategories()" definitely works:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (url_type === "all"){
      allCategories("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/")
    }
    else if (url_type === 'following'){
      allCategories("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/follow")
    }
    else {
      history.push("/404")
    }
  }, []);
```

I've seen this post [react router stacking url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214494/react-router-stacking-url) but I'm not sure how to implement the solution and if our problems are the same.
Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: In your sections array, maybe try changing each "url" key to have slashes in front of them.
Meaning, try "/categories/all" instead of "categories/all", since perhaps without the slash in front, react-router is automatically just appending the url to the previous path.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my url problem. But now I have another problem:
Whenever I want to go from 
"http://localhost:3000/categories/following"
to 
"http://localhost:3000/categories/following"
or the other way around, it doesnt reload.
The url changes, but not the component,

Comment: That's because you're using the same component regardless of what /:url_type is equal to.  If you want the component to change based on the value of ":url_type", you can access the value of url_type in your Categories component by using `props.match.params.url_type` and do some conditional rendering inside your Categories component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React Router will treat paths that start with a slash as absolute paths. Here, your `url` property in your `sections` array are treated as relative paths because they don't start with a slash.

Just add a slash at the beginning of every path in your array:

```js
const sections= [
    { title: 'All Categories', url: '/categories/all' },
    { title: 'Following', url: "/categories/following"},
]
```